Linux doesn't forward a packet because it's bigger than the MTU
I've been trying to route some of my LAN traffic over wireguard to a raspberry pi at my parent's house for when I need my connection to appear from a different country. I have the wireguard connection set up and the firewall rules in my LAN to use the pi as a gateway.
The pi then has two interfaces: eth0 for its upstream, and wg0 for the wireguard tunnel. ipv4 forwarding is enabled, and I have the following iptables rules set up on the appropriate tables (filter/nat):
-A FORWARD -i wg0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.7.7.0/24 -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
---
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

My local network is 10.7.7.0/24. The following pcap shows a capture of both the wg0 and eth0 interfaces when I try to make an https request. My local machine IP is 10.7.7.10, the pi IP is 10.0.0.7, and the server I'm trying to reach is 45.57.91.1
https://app.packetsafari.com/analyze/l/gPPOPI8BN12bKeD_HqdQ
The first 4 frames are as expected:

Packet from local machine to target arrives on wg0
pi SNAT's the packet and forwards to target
target responds to pi
pi DNAT's the response and forwards to local machine

I would expect this to happen for every stream. But interestingly, frame 9 is never forwarded by the pi to my local machine. This totally breaks the stream and the https request, and the remainder of the capture shows tcp trying to recover from the missing packet.

You may have noticed that frame 9 is bigger than the rest, and in fact its the typical MTU of 1500. That indeed is the problem; the wireguard link by default is set to an MTU of 1420, and changing that to 1500 on both ends resolved the issue. But it leaves me wondering...

Questions:

Why doesn't Linux fragment the packet and send it over multiple frames? Is there some kind of setting I'm missing?
If it's not a setting, how does a Linux router do this?
Is there anywhere that the missing packet gets logged? I checked syslog and dmesg, but there's no information there. I was surprised that no log message was generated when the packet was essentially just ignored.

Thanks!


It doesn't fragment because the FLAGS field in the TCP header has the DF (Don't fragment) bit set.
Having DF set is pretty standard these days, as part of MTU discovery.
Probably no way to get it logged. If you could get it logged you would probably be subjectro a DOS attack as packets could be sent faster than you could log them.


How would I get MTU discovery to work across a wireguard link that has lower MTU than the physical NIC?

correctly setting the mtu on the link and having correct routing information should be all that is needed.
